# Ubuntu App Showdown: Commercial applications

Tags: application-development, packaging, mono

Me and a few of my friends decided to create a game for the App showdown. However, we wanted to make a commercial game out of it (for <5$).
So the question is:
If I want to submit a commercial app, what exactly do I have to do? We would be willing to provide it as open source software but want to sell it in USC anyway.
How should I submit the app if we can do that?
(Note: we would only open source if it's required, but would prefer to only share the source with the judges. Is that also possible?).

Also: If I have to upload the source code to the PPA and let it build by ubuntu's build service: How do I do that with Mono-apps? It worked perfectly for other projects where I had CMakeFiles and stuff like that. But for Mono, I only have a MonoDevelop project file - how to do that right?

Thanks

Comment: the first part is covered in the online documentation.  i would re-examine the question to put the mono bit at the front

Answer (score 5):

> If I want to submit a commercial app, what exactly do I have to do?

You can submit commercial open source apps as usual

> we would only open source if it's required, but would prefer to only share the source with the judges. Is that also possible?

No [Ubuntu Appshowdownfaq](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/faq/)  says

> Your app must be Open Source to be eligible for the contest, and you
>   can use any license that complies with the [Open Source definition](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/index.html).

ie, you must provide source code to public

> How to package mono develop project?

[Here is guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Mono) from ubuntu wiki

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) one more question about the "how to do that": So I can simply release under the MIT license but still set a price in SoftwareCenter later? That sound's a bit weird, but I guess that's the way to do it?

Comment: Yeah .Open source software and freeware apps are different

Answer (score 1):

I have a open source application written in mono which builds using a MonoDevelop project file. It has been accepted into debian and is in the offical ubuntu repros.

You can view the code including the packaging for it here: 
https://bitbucket.org/trampster/widemargin/src

The important bit is in your rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

include /usr/share/cli-common/cli.make

override_dh_auto_build:
    xbuild $(CURDIR)/WideMargin.sln /p:Configuration=Release

override_dh_auto_clean:
    xbuild $(CURDIR)/WideMargin.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean

%:
    dh $@
```

This informs xbuild to build from your MonoDevelop solution file.

you will also need to pull in some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts
sudo apt-get install debhelper
sudo apt-get install cli-common-dev
sudo apt-get install mono-xbuild
```

Comment: Thanks trampster, your rules file helped me out. Additionally, I had to add `--exclude-moduleref=glib-2.0.dll` to the end of the file.